# PDO+PHP+SQLITE+PRINT+'ME' = Table result incorrect not what expecting

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I trying to create sqlite database with pdo and echo it out in table it sorts of works but it has some issues and i thought you guys may know it

This is my php code

```
<?php
    try
    {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:randvalue.sqlite');
    $db->exec("CREATE TABLE company (revenue_value INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, month VARCHAR)");

    $start = 2000;
    $end = 2000 * 1.2;
    $numbers = array($start);

    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    $numbers[] = rand($start, $end);
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO company(revenue_value) VALUES ('2000')");
    }
    $numbers[] = $end;

    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO company (revenue_value) VALUES (?)');
    foreach($numbers as $number) {
    $stmt->execute(array($number));
    }

    $months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO company (month) VALUES (?)'); 
    foreach ($months as $month) {
    $stmt->execute(array($month));
    }

    print "<table border=1>";
    print "<tr><td>value</td>";
    print "<td>month</td></tr>";
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM company');

    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        print "<tr><td>".$row['revenue_value']."</td>";
        print "<td>".$row['month']."</td></tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";

    $db = NULL;

    }

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        print 'Exception : '.$e->getMessage();
    }

    ?>
```

and the result

[image: What it displays]

I think the issue is that the number rand and the months array are not executing at the same time there fore creating that table. Is there anyway to make them write in the same columns

Comment: You're using separate INSERT queries for the revenues and the months.  You should be using the same query.

Comment: hmmm now its giving me an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the exec version of inserting:

```
// remove this line
$db->exec("INSERT INTO company(revenue_value) VALUES ('2000')");
```

Use a single insert:

```
try
{
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:randvalue.sqlite');
    $db->exec("CREATE TABLE company (revenue_value INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, month VARCHAR)");

    $start = 2000;
    $end = 2000 * 1.2;
    $numbers = array($start);

    for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
        $numbers[] = rand($start, $end);
    }
    $numbers[] = $end;

    $months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO company (revenue_value, month) VALUES (?, ?)');
    for($j = 0, $count = count($numbers); $j < $count; $j++) {
        $stmt->execute(array($numbers[$j], $months[$j]));
    }
    // then continue on to output the table
```

Comment: nope this time it only show the value and the months doesn't get inserted into tables

Comment: perhaps you didn't remove enough of your code. I'll edit my answer to show all the code in context, not just a snippet. (also did you clear out old data before re-running?)

Comment: also note first posting had a typo or two, notably `j` instead of `$j`

Comment: working ^_^. had to edit it a little bit but at the end it works thank u